# How to update the textbox value based on other textbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I have three input text boxes in my form.

First one is teacher, second one is grade. Now I've the third input text box, where i need to update the value dynamically from these two values as "(teacher)'s (X) class" using JavaScript.

Can anyone help me in writing the code?
Thanks in advance.

here is the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#both').value($('#teacher').val() + "'s " + $('#grade').val());
});

  </script>
```

and my input tags are:

```
<input type="text" name="teacher_name" id="teacher" value="" style="background:#f7f6f2 url(../images/input_02.png) repeat left top;border: 0px;width: 250px;height: 10px;padding: 10px;display: block;">
<input type="text" name="teacher_name" id="grade" value="" style="background:#f7f6f2 url(../images/input_02.png) repeat left top;border: 0px;width: 250px;height: 10px;padding: 10px;display: block;">
<input type="text" name="teacher_name" id="both" value="" style="background:#f7f6f2 url(../images/input_02.png) repeat left top;border: 0px;width: 250px;height: 10px;padding: 10px;display: block;">
```

what are the things i need to add to make my third input field to get updated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `onChange` event that is triggered when an input content changes or the `onBlur` event that is triggered when an input lost the focus:

```
function UpdateInfo()
{
  var teacher = document.getElementById('teacher').val();
  var grade = document.getElementById('grade').val();
  var info = teacher + '\'s '+ grade + ' class';
  document.getElementById('info').value = info;
}

/* Solution 1 (onChange) */
<input id="teacher" type="text" onChange="UpdateInfo();" />
<input id="grade" type="text" onChange="UpdateInfo();" />
<input id="info" type="text" />

/* Solution 2 (onBlur) */
<input id="teacher" type="text" onBlur="UpdateInfo();" />
<input id="grade" type="text" onBlur="UpdateInfo();" />
<input id="info" type="text" />
```

Or using jQuery, you can bind the event at `document.ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    /*
    * binding onChange event here
    * you can replace .change with .blur
    */
    $('#teacher').change(UpdateInfo);
    $('#grade').change(UpdateInfo);
});

   function UpdateInfo()
   {
     var teacher = $('#teacher').val();
     var grade = $('#grade').val();
     var info = teacher + '\'s '+ grade + ' class';
     $('#info').val(info);
   }

<input id="teacher" type="text" />
<input id="grade" type="text" />
<input id="info" type="text" />
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C6mSZ/)**

Comment: no this one is also not working seems everything is fine but in general page also this code is not working

Comment: i thought this will work fine but not working in my code don't know what the fault i'm doing i just updated these in my code but my input fields are not changing....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery it's pretty simple to update the third one when the dom is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#third').value($('#first').val() + "' " + $('#second').val());
});
```

Comment: do you have jquery included on your page?

Comment: what if the values are passing dynamically???http://jsfiddle.net/srinivaswaterdrop01/PUbKj/ see this code

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamically"? no one will help you figure it out if you don't explain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript, you can try this method:

```
var first_val=document.getElementById('first').val();

var second_val=document.getElementById('second').val();

document.getElementById('third').val(first_val + second_val);
```